# search results highlight results using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to achieve search results like YouTube. Just trying, but there are some problems I'm encountering. I have made the working application in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-kyd4g).

I am having a search box when you type anything it will show search results like a dropdown, for an example when you search in youtube you will be able to see results below, same thing/

The problems I'm facing are:

Assume i type "a", now you will be able to see total 6 results in the searched results div having a scroll.

1) So the  1st result itself will show the highlighted css. When i hover or when i navigate with key only the higlight css should come how can i achieve this.

2) so now if i hover on the second or result highlight css will show in the second or third but the 1st result also will show the css. i just want the higlight css at a time only one. (The same feature is there in youtube search)

3) right now only three elements are visible the remaining three are you need to scroll, when i navigate through arrow keys, the scroll is not happening how can i achieve this with [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) API

4) In 6 results the search string is "a", how can i make that string to be strong so it remains as highlighted so whatever you search it should be highlighted

Any help is appreciated! Please let me know if you have any queries

Comment: @Tobias thanks for the edit. How can I achieve the above

Comment: its not clear what you want to achieve !

Comment: @LefiTarik can you check the question now. I have updated it with example. Can you let me know any further details required

Comment: its very clear now especially after @Christopher Ngo nice touch !

Comment: but just a notice, as a developer you should explain well what you need without referring to a functionality related to some vendor, you could just explain what you need simply so people who could help would respond quickly ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With consideration of the code that we updated in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-5fvk9

All you really need is a `onMouseEnter()` event-handler to get everything working.

### Handler

```
  handleMouseEnter = index => {
    this.setState({
      cursor: index,
    })
  }
```

### Markup

```
{searchResults.map((item, index) => {
     return (
         <li
            ref={ref => (this.itemRefs[index] = ref)}
            onClick={() => this.goToItem(index)}
            className={cursor === index ? 'active' : null}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(index)}
         >
          <label className="first-lb">{item.id}</label>
          <label className="second-lb">{item.name}</label>
          <label className="third-lb">{item.address}</label>
        </li>
     )
})}
```

With this, only one of hover-over or arrow-down/arrow-up will take effect at a time. So only one list-item will ever be highlighted.

Comment: okay. thanks christopher. let me check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-kyd4g in sandbox will let you know if anything is wrong. And one more doubt. in my question sandbox the li are seperate to a functional component. In functional component the ref is not there so shall i changed every functional component where ever i need to use ref to class component. Or how should i do that one

Comment: It really depends. Are you stilling using a .map() to iterate and create multiple of that functional component or is it just one item altogether?

Comment: yes, i am using .map. One more hCase is when i type "a" and i hover on 2nd result now if i click on down arrow so 2 and 3 rd search results are comming as highlighted but it should be 3rd should be highlighted isn't can you check this case in your answer codesandbox

Comment: https://ibb.co/0cnZ5g2 check this image you will be able to understand it

Comment: ah okay, looking at the image, that's weird lol. Let me try to find a clean fix. Also for the .map(), just wrap the Component you're returning each time in a div and pass a ref to it. So like:  `<div ref={(ref) => this.myRefs[index] = ref }><Component/></div>`

Comment: i am just trying the solution  in local you can try out here it will be easy already i have created every thing https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-kyd4g

Comment: when i tried the above codesandbox (question one) with the solution in local giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined
 this error. Is it because i am creating ref in parent but i am passing to down as props

Comment: Gotha, I'm looking at the sandbox with your local code. Might take some time to configure everything, but should still be very similar :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196096/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-dileep-thomas).